# Button rotation on click

Tags: java, android, animation, button, rotation

I have a button that when I click it rotate 90deg up. When I click it again it goes 90deg down (get back to previous position).

The issue is that if I spam the button the rotation does go crazy and the button end up pointing to a direction it should not.

here is the code of the rotation:

```
public void onClick(View v){
    float deg = myButton.getRotation();
    if(clicked) deg -= 90;
    else deg += 90;
    myButton.animate().rotation(deg);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "spam the button"?

Comment: Where does the `clicked` variable get set?

Comment: It's like you click the button as fast as possible without stoping

Comment: I forgot about that but it is a global variable that is switch on and off properly (the code I put is just the animation part In my project it is a login thing and take about 100 lines)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first reason why your button is ending with incorrect rotation is because some of the clicks will take into account "wrong" rotation.

The second one is that you do not update "clicked" boolean when button is clicked. I would recommend using ObjectAnimator, since you do not have to rely on current rotating position to rotate.

```
public void onClick(View v){

    ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(myButton, "rotation", clicked ? 90f : 0f).start();    
    clicked = !clicked
}
```

Comment: Glad I could be of help.